# how i can let the bot delete all messages in a specific channel then send's a message and loop this

Tags: discord.js, message

This piece of code deletes any message in a specific channel after 3 seconds

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message =>{
    if (message.channel.id === '899644830848798755')
    {
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000)
    }
});
```

What I want is that after 5 minutes, it will delete its own message and send a message without deleting it. Something like this:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete.then(() => {
          client.channels.cache.get('899644830848798755').send('Hello here!')
    }, 300000);
})
```

and can someone tell me what the difference between `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `bulkDelete` method, it will delete the message every 5 mins. You need to create a function to create your looping, you can also use `setInterval` aswell.

Using `setInterval` method:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
       const chan = client.channels.cache.get('899644830848798755');
        chan.send('Hello here!')
    }, 300000);

})
```

Using `function` method:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
   async function repeat() { //First loop of function declined.
     setTimeout(() => {
        const chan = client.channels.cache.get('899644830848798755');
        chan.send('Hello here!')

        repeat(); //Second loop Accepted for loop
     }, 300000)
   }
   repeat(); //First loop function accepted. Then ignore
})
```

**SetInterval**:

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

setInterval source link: [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

**SetTimeout**:

> The global setTimeout() method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

setTimeout source link: [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)